# List all cosets of An in Sn

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-writing, terminology

Looking for all cosets of $A_n$ in $S_n$.

I know there are only 2 distinct cosets according to Lagrange's Theorem and was told they were sets of all even and odd permutations. It makes sense intuitively but how should I prove it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably know that $A_n$ is normal. Then, since cosets partition the group, the other coset is $S_n - A_n$. You can also write that as $xA_n$ for $x \notin A_n$.